# Access error response data when ResponseContentType.Blob is used

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm facing issue with making request of type `ResponseContentType.Blob` and getting error message in case of failed call.

The code is pretty simple:

```
 let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
 let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob});

 return this.http.post('url', data, options)
      .subscribe(res => ..., err => console.log(err.json()) /* the problem is here */);
```

So having fully clarify JSON as server response in case of error but I can't access it: `err.json()` returns `Blob {size: 194, type: "application/json"}` only data.

How to access response data? I can't change `ResponseContentType`to smth else as I expect file in case of success request.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the blob back to text using a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload). Then, you can convert the text back to json using JSON.parse().

```
err => {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onloadend = (e => {
                     const errorObj=JSON.parse(fr.result);
                     console.log(errorObj);
                 });
  fr.readAsText(err.blob(), 'utf-8');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue: Here you can check my solution

```
(err) => { err.text().then((value) => console.log(value)); }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can just use `.blob()` method:

```
err.blob()
```

The `Body` class that is implemented by `Response` class has the following reponse content accessors:

```
export abstract class Body {
    json(): any
    text(encodingHint: 'legacy'|'iso-8859' = 'legacy'): string
    arrayBuffer(): ArrayBuffer
    blob(): Blob
```

Comment: both err.json() and err.blob() in this case returns same result

Comment: why the call is failed? show screenshot of the response contents from the console

Comment: Call is failed because of some validation logic inside, for example trying to attach file to already deleted request (by other user as example). There are lot of validation logics, so triggering back errors are fine

Comment: `{
data: null,
developerMessage:"Internal server error",
errors: [],
message: "Template with id [...] does not exist"
timestamp: "2017-07-21T08:46:29.528+0000"
}`

Comment: that is obviously not `blob`, it's JSON

Comment: But I expect blob when success action and JSON with detailed error definition when error occurs. So server set all headers correct including "content-type".

Comment: Can you show how you configure the request? I'll try to reproduce